# Generating random variable from array based on weight percentage

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$gender = array(
  'Male'=>30, 
  'Female'=>50,
  'U' =>20);

$total = array_sum(array_values($gender)); 

$current = 0;
$rand = rand(1,$total);

foreach ($gender as $key=>$value)
{
    $current += $value;
    if ($current > $rand)
    {
        echo $key;
    }
}

?>
```

However, when I run it, I sometimes get:

MaleFemaleU

Or:

FemaleU

I set the values for the $gender arrays, and would like to generate the gender based on the percentage given, i.e. in this case: male 30, female 50, and unknown 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop looping when you display the variable.

```
foreach ($gender as $key=>$value)
{
    $current += $value;
    if ($current > $rand)
    {
        echo $key;
        break; // Terminate the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that all those items are reaching the value needed to be echo'd but you aren't putting a line between then.

```
if($current > $rand) {
    echo $key . "<br>";
}
```

Try that so they will display on a new line. From there we can work on the math.

Comment: opps, my original idea was to just display one variable. @rottingham

Answer (score 0):

`rand` will be a value within the range `1..100` since you're summing the values in the array. So then in the `foreach` loop you will print out all the values whenever `rand generates a value small enough to print out all the values.

For example, lets say `$rand` = 1, then `$current` will always be greater than $rand, since it can only as a lowest value have 20.

So, yeah, you most probably wan't to throw in a little `break` there.

**Random thoughts**

I'm a bit suspicious about the logic in this code however, will this give you a correct percentage? That is that 20% of the time when you run this the gender will be `U`, etc. ? Something looks fishy to me.

- A better way of checking percentages (experimental) *

With the current solution I don't think you'll get the distribution of 20% U, 30% Male and 50% Female.
Since U has a lower percentage than `Male` and `Female` in your algorithm are greater than 20 the condition that would render `U` will always generate true for `Male` and `Female` also. Thus, with this algorithm you will never get the value `U`.

I suggest an easier approach by using ranges, that is for example 1-20 = U, 21-50 = Male and 51 - 100 = Female, the order is not important, just that the range equals the precentage. Then it's just a trivial matter of checking which range the `rand` is in.

Comment: I wasn't too sure about using rand... I read if you want to use actual percentages, you would need to make database entries or something like that. Would you have a better way of doing this? @DanielFigueroa